# UITextView appears scrolled halfway down

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode7

I have a view that entirely contains a `UITextView`. Using `scrollRangeToVisible` or `scrollRectToVisible` worked in Xcode 6, but no longer works in Xcode 7. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    textView.text = "super long text...."
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 1))
    self.textView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: true)
}
```

I've tried putting `scrollRangeToVisible` and `scrollRectToVisible` in `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear`, tried changing their range/rect values, and nothing seems to work.

Again, this did work pre-Swift 2. Has anything about scrolling text views changed with the upgrade?